# Explain how the concepts of encapsulation and delegation

Tags: java

So, I'm trying to find how they related to each other, but can't seem to find anything.

a), relate to each other
b), how they differ from each other

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation is a core principal, it refers to the bundling of data with the methods that operate on that data. Basically, logic and data go together. If you have a class, with properties and logic together – it is encapsulated. Helps separation of concerns and reduces surface areas – also supports immutability – since only the object can control the data.

Delegation is when at runtime you can invoke a different object to complete a task dynamically. A useful OO pattern.

Comment: You could just supply the link, instead of copying most of this page:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjQ8Kznod7KAhUL3mMKHZ2BC-gQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.structureofstructures.com%2F2011%2F10%2Fgof-polymorphism-encapsulation.html&usg=AFQjCNHDVPf2bM10jz0Grhwmsqm4UCzboQ&sig2=oMknIQDiQCoAQ56BxMQx8g

Comment: Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist. There is no related post